# Can I create a trigger with a set of instruction with DB2?

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, sql-update, dbeaver

I'm working with DB2 and I have to make a trigger that after a certain update on 'Disponibilita' has to do two differentes operation with the table 'Promozioni'
here the schemas:

```
create table PROMOZIONI (
     PID char(5) not null primary key,
     Valore DEC(4,2) not null,
     NumProdotti INT not null DEFAULT 0 );

create table DISPONIBILITA (
     CodProdotto char(5) not null,
     CodNegozio char(5) not null,
     Quantita INT not null,
     PID char(5) references PROMOZIONI,
     primary key (CodProdotto, CodNegozio));
```

and this is the trigger that obviously doesn't work:

```
Create or replace trigger AggiornaNumProdotti
After Update on Disponibilita 
referencing old as O new as N
for each row
update Promozioni p
SET NumProdotti=NumProdotti+1
Where N.PID is not null and N.PID=p.PID;
UPDATE Promozioni p2
SET NumProdotti=NumProdotti-1
WHERE O.PID is not null and O.PID=p2.PID;
```

is there any way to make a single trigger or i'm force to create two differentes ones for each specific instruction? Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe using Begin Atomic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more than one query you need a `BEGIN` and `END`

```
create table PROMOZIONI (
     PID char(5) not null primary key,
     Valore DEC(4,2) not null,
     NumProdotti INT not null DEFAULT 0 );
```

```
INSERT INTO PROMOZIONI VALUES ('1',1.2,0),
('2',1.2,0)
```

```
create table DISPONIBILITA (
     CodProdotto char(5) not null,
     CodNegozio char(5) not null,
     Quantita INT not null,
     PID char(5) references PROMOZIONI,
     primary key (CodProdotto, CodNegozio));
```

```
INSERT INTO DISPONIBILITA VALUES ('1','1',1,'1')
```

```
Create or replace trigger AggiornaNumProdotti
After Update on Disponibilita 
referencing old as O new as N
for each row
  BEGIN
update Promozioni p
SET NumProdotti=NumProdotti+1
Where N.PID is not null and N.PID=p.PID;
UPDATE Promozioni p2
SET NumProdotti=NumProdotti-1
WHERE O.PID is not null and O.PID=p2.PID;
END;
```

```
UPDATE  DISPONIBILITA SET PID = '2' WHERE PID = '1'
```

```
SELECT * FROM PROMOZIONI
```

| PID | VALORE | NUMPRODOTTI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.20 | -1 |
| 2 | 1.20 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ymy8qDw9)

Comment: i'm pretty sure that you are right and this is the correct answer by the way I'm using dbeaver and i don't if is a problem of IDE or maybe some space/semicolon missing. however if I put your solution on Dbevear it gives me this message with the error:    Errore SQL [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78

Comment: yes you nned to dd a semicolon at the end